# Why does Debian hang after DHCP?

Tags: debian, boot, dhcp

This is my `/etc/networking/interfaces` file:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

And here is a picture of where it is hanging:

[image: ss of problem]

*Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spAwl.jpg*

The cursor is blinking, and I can type; but I'm fairly certain that commands don't work here. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to also keep the loopback in your `interfaces` file. So add these lines:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: How do I edit the file? I'm not sure how to get past what is shown

Comment: @user60365 - How did you get the contents of the file to begin with? Also you can often times boot into single user mode with Linux which would bypass the network detection etc. that's hanging you up. http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-recover-root-password-under-linux-with-single-user-mode/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it has not seemed to work. I know what is in my interfaces file because I recently edited it to the default on the debian wiki, so I just cp'd what I had entered. The following is a picture of what happens after I put "single" after the kernel line: http://imgur.com/YI9XkJ0

Comment: @user60365 - that would seem to indicate that it did not pick up on the single arg. What version of Debian is this?

Comment: Wheezy. I installed from a live image that I got from the official site a few days ago.

Comment: Instead of single you could try this: `init=/bin/sh`. If it works it should just drop you to a prompt where you'll be able to edit the interfaces file.

Comment: I can't tell if it worked or not, I get: "/bin/sh: 0 can't access tty; job control turned off" but I can launch "nano /etc/networking/interfaces" but even after logging in, the document shows as blank

Comment: @user60365 After `init=/bin/sh`, you'll need to at least remount the root read-write: `mount -o remount,rw /`. Maybe also `mount /proc`. To reboot, do `remount -o remount,ro /` first.

Comment: @Gilles then what?

Comment: @user60365 Then launch the editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have network shares configured in your /etc/fstab they might prevent the system from booting if they cannot be mounted.